# Can every user restore a dump using pg_restore?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pg-restore

I created a user on local PostgreSQL instance using this command:

```
create role testuser with login password 'test'
```

Then I created a blank database and used `pg_restore` to restore a backup on the newly created database using this command:

```sh
pg_restore -c -h 172.27.211.11 -U testuser -d abcd_test1  "E:\testbackup_20180509_2330.backup"
```

Surprisingly, the backup got restored. Does that mean all users have the right to restore the database?

Is there any way to prevent a user from restoring the database?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you gave `testuser` the `CREATE` permission on `abcd_test1`, that can only work if all objects in the dump are in the `public` schema. Otherwise you'd get errors as soon an `pg_restore` tries to create the schemas.

What you observe is caused by two things:

1. Every database has `CONNECT` permissions for `PUBLIC` by default.
2. the `public` schema has `CREATE` permissions for `PUBLIC` by default.

Since `PUBLIC` is the pseudo-role that everybody belongs to, `testuser` can connect and create objects in the `public` schema.

It is a good idea to restrict permissions on every new PostgreSQL database:

```
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE abcd_test1 FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

Then you can deal out permissions in a more restrictive fashion.