# PostgreSQL pg_restore using a user other than superuser

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

Consider a situation in which the following are true:

- There exists a collection of databases which is a PostgreSQL database cluster, associated with PostgreSQL version 16. Here in this description, let's call that cluster "Pgdbc1".
- Attached to Pgdbc1, there exists a PostgreSQL user which is a superuser. Call that user "PostgresSuperUser".
- Attached to Pgdbc1, there exists a PostgreSQL user which is a user other than a superuser. Call that user "Pguser99".
- As a database in Pgdbc1, there exists a database which is owned by Pguser99. Call that database "Db55OwnedByPgUser99".
- Backups of databases in Pgdbc1, including Db55OwnedByPgUser99, are routinely done using pg_dump app, included with PostgreSQL version 16, and using the PostgresSuperUser.
- Those backup files are saved in archive format generated by pg_dump. So, in case of needing to restore a database, the pg_restore app, associated with PostgreSQL version 16 or higher, would be required.
- Let's use "Db55BackupArchive324" to refer to a collection of files/folders which consist of one particular instance of a backup of Db55OwnedByPgUser99, done using pg_dump, associated with PostgreSQL version 16, and using an archive format.
- Let's use "OperatingSystemUserDFG" to refer to a person (entity) which:
  □ Has access rights which allow execution of the pg_restore app.
  □ Has read access to Db55BackupArchive324.
- OperatingSystemUserDFG
  □ Does NOT have password of PostgresSuperUser or any superuser
  □ runs pg_restore, and when running pg_restore,
  ®Uses Pguser99 as the user, which is provided to pg_restore app.
  ®Uses the password which Pguser99 used on Pgdbc1.
  ®Restores Db55OwnedByPgUser99 on Pgdbc1.
- Given the fact that PostgresSuperUser did the instance of running pg_dump which led to the creation of database backup file named "Db55BackupArchive324", can someone use pg_restore to successfully restore Db55BackupArchive324 using the Pguser99 and password of Pguser99, rather than the PostgresSuperUser and password of PostgresSuperUser, and do the restore in cluster Pgdbc1?

[Can every user restore a dump using pg_restore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279578/can-every-user-restore-a-dump-using-pg-restore) is a similar question, but not really the same.

- Attached question. What about doing the restore to a different cluster, call it "Pgdbc2"? In order to achieve such a restore on Pgdbc2 using the Pguser99 and password of Pguser99, on Pgdbc2, would you do the following?

  1. Make sure there is a user named "Pguser99", and use the same character string for password of that Pguser99 as was used for Pguser99 on Pgdbc1.
  2. Make sure there is a database which is owned by Pguser99, and named "Db55OwnedByPgUser99", which is the same name as was used on Pgdbc1.

Comment: There's a lot of distracting odd codes in that, but I think the essential bits you need to know is (1) the operating-system user is irrelevant (assuming the file is readable) and (2) whether a non-superuser can restore the backup depends on what is in the backup and whether they need to create a database to restore into.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by restore.  1) This `pg_restore -f test_dump_sql test.out` will 'restore' as plain text to a file and the only permissions needed are those to read  `test.out`.  You could anything you want in that file and then use it with `psql` to restore an actual database. 2) This `pg_restore  -d <some_db> -C -U <some_user>  -O test.out`  will restore with permissions on database objects reset to `some_user`.

Comment: @ Richard Huxton. Thank you. Those essential bits are helpful. Apologies for my distracting odd codes.

Comment: @ Adrian Klaver. Thank you, and of course I should have been more precise with concepts related to "restore". Now I understand that anyone who has access to a file which results from doing an instance of running pg_dump could use that file to restore the contents of the database, no matter what user did the running of pg_dump. Previously I had the idea there might be some sort of file access restriction or encryption attached to a backup file, depending on which user did the running of pg_dump. Now I understand that there is NOT any sort of restriction which is attached to the backup file.